# Insert Textbox.text "123456" as password in Mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, password-encryption

I want to create a User and Insert to an exist table with a mysql query.

I have this in C#:

```
using (OdbcCommand cmd6 = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO users (id,Name,login,pass) VALUES ('" + textboxID.Text + "','" + textboxNAME.Text + textboxLOGIN.Text + "','" + textboxPASS.Text + "' )", conn6))
```

I want to get the pass from textboxPASS.Text and inserts as encrypted, because now it inserts as text.

Note.-
If I put "pass123456" in my textboxPASS...It take it and inserts as text: "pass123456".
And when I see the table, the others already existing users have encrypted passwords. (around 40 numeric characters).
But my new user has that field as text "pass123456".

I hope you can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Bobby Tables cries a little cry. Please please please use parameters. And please don't store passwords, even encrypted. You store *cryptographic hashes* of passwords *only*.

Comment: This code might be vulnerable to sql injection. Dont use it like this if you are doing it on some live project

Comment: @AmarnathRShenoy there is no "might be" here. This is absolutely trivially vulnerable.

Comment: @MarcGravell was trying to be nice :D

Comment: Without knowing what encryption scheme your current passwords are generated with how can we show you how to encrypt your plaintext passwords?

Comment: @Austin is right. Your question states _"I want to [..] insert as encrypted [..] when I see the table, the others already existing users have encrypted passwords"_. Then look through the existing code to see what encryption or hashing algorithm is being used, we cannot do so.

Comment: This is what the table shows for the users that password is "123456":
2251022057731868917119086224872421513662

Answer (score 1):

The SQL is doing what it is told. If you want to run some cryptographic operation on the data first, you must do that:

```
// note using ? since ODBC has poor support for named parameters, IIRC
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(
    "INSERT INTO users (id,Name,login,pass) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", conn))
{
    // this is most likely a hash op, and probably involves salt of some kind
    var cryptoPass = SomeCryptoOperation(..., textboxPASS.Text);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", textboxID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", textboxNAME.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("login", textboxLOGIN.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", cryptoPass);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: So much THANKS Marc Gravell, let me try and I'll tell you if it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the encrypt function eg.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users VALUES(@Username, @Password)"))
    {
        cmd6.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text.Trim());
        cmd6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Encrypt(txtPassword.Text.Trim()));
```

for more advanced encryption check for AES functions